# problems with the stamps of html code by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need that the javascript function stamp the code exactly when i put the  `<div id="">`

I tried  with:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "myUrl"
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function(data, status){
        $.each(data, function(i,item){
            document.getElementById("livello").innerHTML='<h2> '+ item.nome+' </h2>';   
        });
   }
});
```

but It stamp only the last element

I tried also

```
$.ajax({
    url: "myUrl"
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function(data, status){
        $.each(data, function(i,item){
            var a ='<h2>'+ item.nome+' </h2>';  
            output.append(a);
        });
    }
});
```

this stamp all that I need but the graphic of jquery it is a mess... (also importing the libraries)

Comment: Can you explain what is meant by "stamp"? Do you mean timestamp?

Comment: Amigo, parece-me que você é brasileiro. Refaça a pergunta em português aqui no comentário que eu te respondo e traduzo. [Amigo, looks like by your code that you are also brazilian. Ask again in portuguese in the comments section so I'll be able to translate-it for ya]

Answer (score 3):

Look at what it is doing

```
document.getElementById("livello").innerHTML='<h2> '+ item.nome+' </h2>';
```

You are overwriting the innerHTML on each iteration, you are not adding to it.

```
    var elem = $("#livello");
    var strOut = elem.html(); // or = "";
    $.each(data, function(i,item){
        strOut  += '<h2> '+ item.nome+' </h2>';   
    });
    elem.html(strOut);
```

Comment: sorry ...for stamp I mean print

epascarello yes It work perfectly!! thank you very much!!!!!